# Erro ao baixar um site feito em CodeIgniter para minha máquina localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter

Baixei um website já feito com o framework codeigniter em minha máquina, coloquei no localhost mas apresenta o erro " ", acho que preciso definir o banco de dados, se for isso, como faço isso?

Existe algum arquivo como o wordpress que tem o wp-config?

Comment: Se for só o banco de dados pode configurar em `/application/config/database.php` mas deve estar aparecendo esse erro em branco por causa da configuração do seu php.ini, de uma olhada em error_reporting e display_errors

Answer (score 1):

Como não disse qual é o erro, apenas "", fica difícil acertar com precisão. Mas vamos lá, que uma hora dá certo.

Se o site necessita se conectar a um `banco de dados`, você precisa ter esse ele criado em sua máquina¹, seja em `mysql`, `postgres`, `sqlite` etc, e imaginando que você não está conseguindo acessar esse site pela sua máquina por esse erro, então para definir a conexão com esse banco de dados, vá até `/application/config/` e altere o arquivo `database.php` nas seguintes linhas:

```
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'usuario_dono_do_banco',
'password' => 'senha',
'database' => 'nome_do_banco',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
```

Em `dbdriver` deixe como `'mysqli'` se for MySQL, e `'postgre'` se for PostgreSQL.

Mais dúvidas sobre a conexão com o `banco de dados` podem ser tiras [aqui](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html) na documentação oficial do `ci`.

Um outro ponto importante de se olhar é caso o site que tem em mãos, se na estrutura raiz exista um arquivo `.htaccess`, onde muitas vezes define que a `url` possa se tornar mais curta, usando o `mod_rewrite` do `apache`. Então, consulte isso executando um arquivo `.php` com a seguinte linha:

```
<?php print_r(apache_get_modules()); ?>
```

Considere verificar se o módulo `mod_rewrite` apareça na listagem. Se não aparecer, no terminal utilize o comando `sudo a2enmod rewrite` se for `linux/ubuntu` ou considere excluir o arquivo `.htaccess`.

¹ Caso não seja possível acesso remoto ao banco já existente.